# SQL query to display db data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following database table:

Answer

```
MemberID | QuestionNo  | AnswerNo   | AnswerString
10       | 1           |     2      | q1 anwer2
10       | 2.1         |     3      | q2.1 answer3
10       | 2.2         |     5      | q2.2 answer5
10       | 7           |     1      | q7 answer 7
11       | 1           |     3      | q1 anwer 3
11       | 3           |     1      | q3 answer 1
11       | 5           |     4      | q5 anwer 4
```

Each member answers different set of questions based on the answers of previous questions.
I want to show the answer in the following format

```
MemberID | 1  | 2.1 | 2.2 | 3   | 5  |  7
10       | 2  |  3  | 5   |NULL |NULL| 1
11       | 3  |NULL |NULL | 1   | 4  |NULL
```

Can I do it only in SQL Server 2005? Or I need to use ASP.net to process it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking to pivot data - change columnar data into rows.  The old school way is to use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28SQL.90%29.aspx) statements - as of SQL Server 2005 you can use the [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.90%29.aspx) command.  I'll leave it to someone else to provide the PIVOT example.

```
SELECT t.memberid,
       CASE WHEN t.questionno = 1 THEN t.answerno ELSE NULL END AS 1,
       CASE WHEN t.questionno = 2.1 THEN t.answerno ELSE NULL END AS 2.1,
       CASE WHEN t.questionno = 2.2 THEN t.answerno ELSE NULL END AS 2.2,
       CASE WHEN t.questionno = 3 THEN t.answerno ELSE NULL END AS 3
       CASE WHEN t.questionno = 5 THEN t.answerno ELSE NULL END AS 5
       CASE WHEN t.questionno = 7 THEN t.answerno ELSE NULL END AS 7
  FROM ANSWER t
```

It's not clear to me what the data type of the questionno column is, update to suit if necessary.

**If users can define their own questions, you have to use dynamic SQL**.  You'll need to get a list of questionno's first, and then construct the CASE statements based on those results.  Likewise for PIVOT...

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @questionno [data type here]

SET @SQL = 'SELECT t.memberid,'

DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
  SELECT t.questionno
    FROM ANSWER t
GROUP BY t.questionno
ORDER BY t.questionno

OPEN c1

FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @questionno 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  SET @SQL = @SQL + ' CASE WHEN t.questionno = '+ @questionno +' THEN t.answerno ELSE NULL END AS '+ @questionno','

  FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @questionno 
END

CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'NULL FROM ANSWER t '

EXEC(@SQL)
```

The `NULL FROM`... is because I'm too lazy to get rid of the comma that would come from the last CASE statement.

Comment: I don't think PIVOT will be able to make dynamic columns any better than the case statement can.  One option is to generate dynamic SQL and then exec it.

Comment: What if the user can add questions on their own? I can't hard-code the questionno in the sql.

Comment: I like the idea of using NULL to overcome the extra comma - a better solution than shortening the string. *Files away in back of brain for future reference*

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no, because you're trying to run the values of the QuestionNo column across your display. So I don't think you'll be able to create an SQL query to represent the data in this fashion.

That said, any client program to re-present the data in this fashion should be trivial as you're just transposing data. You wouldn't necessarily need a .NET program. A simple script should suffice.

(Thinking about it a bit more, if you wanted to use T-SQL with its additional flow control, string operations, cursors, etc. you could probably do it. But this sort of scripting would be easier to do in a client program.)

EDIT: Hadn't come across PIVOT before (see other answers). Looks like it will help, but requires a bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pivot query. Microsoft has examples [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) and there are plenty more to be found on Google.

Comment: What if the user can add questions on their own? I can't hard-code the questionno in the sql.
PIVOT 
( 
    SUM(AnswerNo) 
    FOR QuestionNo IN ([I cannot hard-code this]) 
) p

Comment: For MS SQL it requires eval'd SQL. The example at http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx (in the section "Dynamic Pivot Table Queries in SQL") looks as simple and as reasonable as it gets.